# 2D array error - Javascript string to number convertion

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, error-handling

Quiestion-1:

I have 2D array like this:

```
var t = [ ['1','2015','Name1','pic1'], ['2','2015','Name2','pic2'], ['3','2015','Name3','pic3'] ];
```

Why is a) and b) working fine

a)

```
var x = 2; var L5 = '<img class="demo" src="b2/'+ t[x][3] +'.png">';
```

b)

```
for (var i = 0; i < (t.length); ++i) { var L5 = '<img class="demo" src="b2/'+ t[i][3] +'.png">'; }
```

but c), d), e) and f) are not working, I get error like TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 't[x][3]') - If I use alert (typeof x) then type is number

c)

```
for (var i = 0; i < (t.length); ++i) { var x = +t[i][0]; var L5 = '<img class="demo" src="b2/'+ t[x][3] +'.png">'; }
```

d)

```
for (var i = 0; i < (t.length); ++i) { var x = parseInt(+t[i][0]); var L5 = '<img class="demo" src="b2/'+ t[x][3] +'.png">'; }
```

e) I have also try to use `Number(x), x = 0+t[i][0]; x = 1*t[i][0]; x = t[i][0]/1; Number(t[i][0])`,

It is like if I get the index number from array, convert it from string to number x then I can not use it as a index number into array like t[x][3] +'.png">';

But this work all fine if the number is coming from like `var x = 2;` or from for a loop like `for (var i = 0; i < (t.length); ++i)`

Quiestion-2:

How can I upload / download same "var t = [...]" as a file with help from JSON without using the typical JSON `[ key1:value1, key2:value2, key3:value3 ]` setup but only value like I am doing in Question-1.
I like a lot to use the 2D format `arr[x][y]` but without key1, key2... if possible.

Thanks

Comment: The main array `t` only has 3 elements. The last sub-array has a `3` in position 0, so `t[3]` is `undefined`.

Comment: I manually made this demo, have not run it, the main array is much bigger like `var t = [
['1','2015','BMW','1 116d','Dísel','Sjálfsk.','4 dyra','4760000','B','205/55R16','112','4.45','Afturdrif ','6302110500','1600 cc','0','103134','40986','47690','113900','124900','102900','114900','100900','116900','97900','113900','111900','121900','100900','112900','98900','113900','95900','111900','1','BMW_1_4 dyra','2','2','2','2','3','2','1','2','4','5'],....` or around 400 lines like this  so my demo above probably have this error

Comment: Well what you can do is add code to check whether `t[x]` is defined before trying to access `t[x][3]`.

Comment: I will try that, I have been using arr[x][y] a lot because it give me fast lookup of data by using index. All have been working fine until I was going to sort this big amount of data. Then I lost the index ID which I was also using as a name of picture for each line. So I add the picture name to the array and use the first ID number in same array to point to the picture I want to get! (hope my english is ok?)

Comment: Yes, I understand (basically, I think) what you are doing, and there is no problem as long as the "links" in your array are OK.  It's easy to test - just compare `t[x]` to `undefined` and only access `t[x][3]` if it is not `undefined`.